# Using DSC to create a SQL database (i.e. tables, columns, datatypes, etc)

Tags: sql-server, dsc

There are DSC resources to [install SQL Server](https://github.com/PowerShell/xSQLServer), but there do not appear to be any resources to install a database into SQL Server (i.e. create the tables, columns, datatypes, stored procedures, etc.).

Currently I am using a [Script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/scriptresource?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) resource to run a `install_my_database.sql` file, but I was looking for a more DSC-way of doing this (a resource that I can say "Ensure this table, ensure these columns, etc").

Is anyone aware of anything that would meet my needs?

Please note that I am aware that I could write my own DSC resources to do this (and that will be a fun side-project in the future), but I'm really looking for an implemented solution - I'm trying to not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: A quick search on the PowerShell gallery yields [this](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/xDatabase/1.5.0.0), which leverages a DACPAC. (You really don't want to be "ensuring" individual tables/columns, as it would be incredibly hard if not impossible for a script to transmogrify an arbitrarily modified database into "what it should be" -- unless you don't mind data loss.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert That's exactly what I was looking for. I'd never heard of DACPACs before, but it sounds like they do exactly what I'm looking for (i.e. safely ensure a database to a server). Please put this as an answer, and I'll mark it correct - thanks! DACPACs are also easily creatable from an existing database, or from Visual Studio using the "SQL Server Database" project type, so it's no extra effort for me to use them - and it should be much easier to maintain than a SQL script in TFS - all round win!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can package the database and deploy it as a [DACPAC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee210546) (or a BACPAC, which is a DACPAC with a punny name that includes data as well). Installing, upgrading and removing installed databases can be done in a structured way with this, as opposed to running ad-hoc scripts.

The PowerShell gallery hosts a DSC resource for this called [xDatabase](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/xDatabase/1.5.0.0). Disclaimer: I have no personal experience with it.